# PDF417 or RSS_EXTENED codes that can be scanned by Barcode Scanner plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

There's a great barcode scanner for PhoneGap. It's documentation [says, that](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner#android) it supports, among many others, also scanning of [RSS_EXPANDED](https://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=925&q=RSS_EXPANDED&oq=RSS_EXPANDED&gs_l=img.3...1236.2044.0.2295.2.2.0.0.0.0.64.119.2.2.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.61.img..2.0.0.JXQG6y4Eb-c) codes (on Android platform only) and [PDF417](https://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=925&q=RSS_EXPANDED&oq=RSS_EXPANDED&gs_l=img.3...1236.2044.0.2295.2.2.0.0.0.0.64.119.2.2.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.61.img..2.0.0.JXQG6y4Eb-c#hl=pl&tbm=isch&q=PDF417) codes (on all platforms except iOS). However, I wasn't able to scan any of this kind of codes, with my Android-based application, even though I found many examples of such codes.

Can anyone provide any example of these code types, that any PhoneGap application, using the Barcode Scanner plugin, can really scan / read?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that version of the plugin doesn't support PDF417 and RSS_EXPANDED. I ran into this today and added support to the fork I'm maintaining: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner